# Updates needed to ensure successful dual-boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, drivers

I am wanting to get a list of different updates that a computer should have done in preparation for dual-booting to ensure that everything will go smoothly.

The reason I'm asking this is because I have a laptop that's been through numerous dual-boot configurations. At one point, I only had Linux Mint running and my Windows (for VS development) in VirtualBox. Eventually, I removed everything and reinstalled Windows 8 on my machine. **When I did that, a number of things weren't working properly**; installing drivers have fixed most of them. Since then, I've been updating as many drivers as I can find pertaining to my model and hardware.

I want to make sure I cover all of my bases and I don't end up ruining my boot-loader or anything important.

What other items should I consider updating or reconfiguring before I dual-boot again?

I have a [Toshiba Satellite S855D-S5120](http://www.toshiba.com/us/computers/laptops/satellite/S850/S855D-S5120)

- AMD Quad-Core A10-4600M Accelerated Processor
- AMD Radeon™ HD 7660G Graphics Engine
- 8GB DDR3 1600MHz Memory
- 750GB (5400rpm, Serial ATA) Hard Drive
- 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN
- 10/100 Ethernet LAN
- 1-USB (2.0) port with Sleep and Charge, 2-USB (3.0) ports
- HDMI® output port
- Li-Ion (48Wh, 6-Cell) Battery

Also, it is safe to assume that I will only be installing Linux Distro's alongside Windows 8. Starting with [Bodhi](http://www.bodhilinux.com/about_bodhi.php) which is based on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

> I am wanting to get a list of different updates that a computer should have done in preparation for dual-booting

There is no connection between updates and dual-boot. Windows updates do not affect bootloader configuration.

> When I did that, a number of things weren't working properly; installing drivers have fixed most of them.

A clean installation of Windows **needs** drivers.

The thing with Windows 8 is that due to its fast startup options [Linux will be affected](http://www.ghacks.net/2013/01/10/windows-8s-fast-startup-does-not-play-well-with-dual-boot-systems/) (You will have readonly acces to NTFS partitions, some hardware may not work - like network card). See this also [Why disable Fast Boot on Windows 8 when having dual booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452071/why-disable-fast-boot-on-windows-8-when-having-dual-booting)